# \n is not working with text node in javascript

Tags: javascript, newline, textnode

In this code in TextNode i tried to put strings in different line by using `\n` in the following code:

```
var CC = function(valu, name, age){
        var parent = document.createElement("div");
            parent.id = valu;
            parent.setAttribute("onclick", "info()");
            parent.style.color = "blue";
        var heading = document.createTextNode("phone no: "+valu+"\n Name:"+name+" \nAge: "+age);
        parent.appendChild(heading);    

        var ele = document.getElementById("main");
        ele.appendChild(parent);

        }(valu, name, age);
```

and then when i tried this, in the line: `var heading = document.createTextNode("phone no: "+valu+"\n Name:"+name+" \nAge: "+age); \n` was not working. should i dont use `\n` in this `TextNode` or i am using it in a wrong way?

Comment: The break tag `<br/>`

Comment: You should avoid binding events with setAttribute, instead, would be better if you bind with [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) or at least [DOM 0 onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onclick):  `parent.onclick = info;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### ISSUE

The issue is that **[`document.createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createTextNode)** prevents the text from rendering as HTML.

You need to use **[`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement)** if you want to render HTML.

---

### CHANGES

To get a working demo of your code, I had to make some improvisations.

I changed the following:

- Converted `CC()` to a simple function since I don't know what the rest of your code looks like.
- Changed the `valu` parameter to `phone`.  Not sure what `valu` means.
- Added a global variable `id` that increments each time you call the `CC()` method so that the divs being created maintain unique ids.
- Inside the `CC()` function, I created text node variables that represent each parameter being passed in (name, phone, and age).
- Changed `setAttribute()` to `addEventListener()`.
- Instead of one long `appendChild()`, I just did multiple showing each step, with `document.createElement("br")` in between each text node.
- Also note, that I added the `info()` function that alerts the div's information that's being clicked.

---

### JAVASCRIPT

```
var id = 1;

function info()
{
    alert(this.innerText);
}

function CC (name, phone, age) 
{
    var parent = document.createElement("div"),
        nameText = document.createTextNode("Name: " + name),
        phoneText = document.createTextNode("Phone: " + phone),
        ageText = document.createTextNode("Age: " + age);

    parent.id = 'div' + id.toString();
    parent.style.color = "blue";
    parent.addEventListener("click", info, false);

    parent.appendChild(nameText);
    parent.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    parent.appendChild(phoneText);
    parent.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    parent.appendChild(ageText);
    parent.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

    document.getElementById("main").appendChild(parent);
    id++;
}

CC('John Doe', '123.456.7890', '40');
```

### ***[See working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DotNetScott/c2FYe/)***

Comment: @sanmevgsaini - Create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate your issue and I'll help you fix it.

Comment: i dont know how to create a js fiddle presentation but i can give you all the code i have:

Comment: @sanmevgsaini - I went ahead and created a jsFiddle that fixes your issue and updated my answer.